Is there a way to expand this div to 100% of the screen without the scrollbar to appear?
I have this html and tailwindcss code:
<div class="flex flex-col min-h-screen">
    <div class="bg-black text-white h-[65px]">
        This is a navbar, but 65px is just an example, the height is dynamic on each page
    </div>

    <div class="bg-blue-200 flex-1">
        Body here

        <div class="bg-pink-300">
            I would like this to be 100% height of the screen but without the need to scroll the page. If I use `h-screen` the scroll appears.
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bg-black text-white h-[65px]">
        This is a footer, but 65px is just an example, the height is dynamic on each page
    </div>
</div>

Ideally if dynamically the navbar or the footer change their height the height should change accordingly.
I can fix this using flex flex-col flex-1 on the parents divs.
But in some pages I can't. Because sometimes I cannot change the parent divs classes.
Obviously I'm not looking for a Javascript solution.
Can you help me?

Your question is confusing. If you want an element to be 100% of the screen height, then .h-screen will do exactly that. A scroll bar appears because you have other elements present, so your document height is greater than the screen height.
If however, you just want the pink element to fill the remaining available space (which is always less than 100% of the screen height), then simply set that element to grow, using the flex property .grow and making that element a child of a .flex element.

…sometimes I cannot change the parent divs classes

Why not?

Because I'm editing components inside other components and I cannot change the parents.
Can you write a small example editing mine with flex and grow without a parent "flex"? I tried, but it seems impossible!

For example take this: https://play.tailwindcss.com/Jw2XAGph6v.

Sure: https://play.tailwindcss.com/DtAMEfm9r8

But, sorry, you removed the empty div I added to simulate my real code. The empty div is the issue I'm trying to fix!

The empty div is the issue, you have an html problem. You either need to remove it, or add duplicated classes flex grow flex-col to it. There's literally zero point to a  with no attributes. Here is your code, with the needlessly duplicated html still in place, updated: https://play.tailwindcss.com/QdaDX73aRV

Dear Seth, I cannot change the parent divs because I'm editing just the child div: this is an app and I can only writ ethe content od the child div. I cannot change the parent!

If you cannot change the html then Tailwind seems a poor choice of framework, given that it is designed to work by writing html.

And what about using normal CSS?
